# Link text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code for a typewriter effect, and I'm wondering how I could make "Text" and "Text2" link to "text.com" and "text2.com" respectively.

I tried using `('Text'.link('http://text.com'));`

However, this just made it very slow and not really act how it should or at least how it was prior to replacing it.

```js
// set up text to print, each item in array is new line
var aText = new Array("Text", "Text2");
var iSpeed = 100; // time delay of print out
var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines
 
var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var iRow; // initialise current row
 
function typewriter()
{
 sContents =  ' ';
 iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex-iScrollAt);
 var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");
 
 while ( iRow < iIndex ) {
    sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
 }
 destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) + "_";
 if ( iTextPos++ == iArrLength ) {
    iTextPos = 0;
    iIndex++;
    if ( iIndex != aText.length ) {
       iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
       setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
    }
 } else {
    setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
   }
}

typewriter();
```

Comment: Have you done any basic testing of this code yet? For example, you have typewriter() in quotes when you call it in setTimeout. Fix these issues before you post your code.

Comment: @ecg8 I believe it's old school but you can quote the argument in setTimeout and it's eval'ed.

Comment: @Jim W Okay, well you may be right but I get errors with it.

Comment: @ecg8, the code works perfectly fine and I did not write it myself as I have little to no experience with javascript.